# concatenate variables in angular property element

Tags: html, angular, variables

I comment, and looked here and I can not find the solution, my problem is the following:

in my html template in angular, I need to pass a series of data to the metadata property of a button, I can't get the correct way to successfully concatenate the variable that contains the value.

this should be the html element:

```
<mati-button clientId="clientId" flowId="flowId" color="green"metadata='{"user_id":"1234778","email":"som@som.com"}'/>
```

I tried several ways but I can't insert the respective values....

example:

```
<mati-button  metadata='{"userID": "{{user.id}}" }'></mati-button>
```

unsuccessfully...

Comment: ` metadata='{"userID": user.id }'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
metadata='{" userID ": {{user.id}}}'
```

in the end I got it. Apparently I don't know why, but the third-party script hides that parameter and it couldn't be debugged in the console, but it does receive them without any problem! Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `mati-button` is an Angular component with `metadata` as `Input()`, you are probably looking for

```
<mati-button 
  [clientId]="clientId"
  [flowId]="flowId" 
  [color]="green"
  [metadata]="{ userId: '1234778', email: 'som@som.com'}"
></mati-button>
```

See the [guide on property binding](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding) to learn more:

> To bind to an element's property, enclose it in square brackets, `[]`, which identifies the property as a target property. [...] The brackets, `[]`, cause Angular to evaluate the right-hand side of the assignment as a dynamic expression. Without the brackets, Angular treats the right-hand side as a string literal and sets the property to that static value.

By "dynamic expression" they mean JS-expressions, i.e., a public variable available through the component's TypeScript, a boolean expression, an array, or, like in your case, a JS-object that you can construct inline.

Comment: that's my main problem that it is not a component of angular, it is a component of a third

Comment: It doesn't matter, this answer should work. And if it doesn't then there's something else wrong here. You can replace `'1234778'` with `user.id`

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this

```
<mati-button  metadata="{'userID': user.id }"></mati-button>
```